# How to add dividers/spaces between Adapters of concatadapter in Recylerview

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-concatadapter

How to add dividers/spaces between Adapters of concatadapter in Recylerview

We can create ConcatAdapter using multiple adapters in Android  using

```
concatenated = new ConcatAdapter(adaplterlist);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(concatenated);
```

I want to create a horizontal recylerview using

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),
                RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

However I want to have a divider or space bewteen 2 Adapters , Like the Image below

[image]

`DividerItemDecoration` is not useful.

how can we do this.

Answer (score 3):

You could try adding another adapter between two adapters with 1 item in it and set view's size to exact space you need.

```
class SpaceItemAdapter(private val spacingPx: Int) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SpaceItemViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SpaceItemViewHolder {
        val view = FrameLayout(parent.context).apply {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(spacingPx, 1)
        }
        return SpaceItemViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SpaceItemViewHolder, position: Int) {}

    override fun getItemCount() = 1
}

class SpaceItemViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
```

Comment: how can we do the same in compose

Comment: @1234567 maybe `Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(spaceInDp))` would help?